# Convert excel file to numpy array matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to read in an excel file (with lines of strings) as a numpy array in my code.

So this is what I do:

```
import numpy, pandas as np, pd
seq1 = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
seq1 = np.array(seq1)
```

This is what I get when I print my seq1:

```
[['coq' 'chat' 'loup' 'chien' nan nan]
['ours' 'lion' 'chien' 'loup' 'singe' nan]
['ours' 'lion' 'loup' 'singe' 'coq' 'chien]]
```

However, I would like to have this:

```
[['coq', 'chat', 'loup', 'chien'],
['ours', 'lion', 'chien', 'loup', 'singe']
['ours', 'lion', 'loup', 'singe', 'coq', 'chien']]
```

So I need to get rid of the nan and add comma's.

Can anyone help? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `dataframe`, the result of the `read`?  `pandas` is inserting the `nan` for missing values.  `np.array(seq1)`, or equivalently `seq1.to_numpy()` produces a valid 2d array.  That's what you get.  What you would like is not valid a valid numpy array.  It's more like a Python list of lists.  You may need to read some more basic Python and numpy.

Comment: I fixed the problem by creating a loop